# How is the difference between httpd and taosadapter in TDengine database?

Tags: tdengine

In latest TDengine develop branch, taosadapter is provided to replace httpd for restful service.
Both taosadapter and httpd use port 6041, I am wondering what is the difference between taosadaptor and httpd in TDengine database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The httpd is the buildin restful agent of TDengine running as a thread while taosAdaptor servers as separate process. They are both http proxys. However, taosAdaptor supports more features than the original http, for example, taosAdaptor support using schemaless method to writting data into TDengine.